# How can I make ActiveMQ/Camel remove the current message from the queue AFTER completion?

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a Camel route, which consumes from an activeMQ queue. Right now the message gets removed from the queue, when it is processed by the Camel route.

What I want, is that it remains in the queue, until my route is finished and the message is forwarded to another queue, to stop messages from disappearing when my Camel crashes.

At this moment messages from the queue will be lost forever, if Camel crashes when it is processing a message.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Read about transacted acknowledge mode. And transactions: http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html

Answer (score 3):

Adding `acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` makes Camel only remove the message when the route is finished succesfully:

`from("activemq:some.queue.name?acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE")`

Camel is also locking these messages to prevent other Camel instances or threads from processing the same message.

Comment: Camel is already putting a lock on the messages itself, I tested this with 2 Camel instances, and they do not 'steal' eachothers messages.

Comment: FYI: you can edit your answer instead just commenting on your own post.